Non-degenerate bilinear form on manifold
Let $M$ be a smooth (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold and $E$ a vector bundle over $M$ equipped with a non-degenerate bundle metricc $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{E}$, i.e. a family of non-degenerate symmetric bilinear forms $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{E_{p}}$ on $E_{p}$ depending smoothly on $p$. Then, I can define a symmetric bilinear form on the level of sections $\Gamma^{\infty}_{c}(E)$ via
$$(\cdot,\cdot)_{E}:=\int_{M}\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{E}\,d\mathrm{vol}_{g}.$$

Question: Is $(\cdot,\cdot)_{E}$ non-degenerate?

I have seen this be claimed in various sources. One concrete example is the non-degenaracy of the Hodge pairing $\int\alpha\wedge\ast\beta$  on pseudo-Riemannian manifold, etc. But somehow, I am not able to prove it. Essentially, we have to show that
$$\forall\varphi\in\Gamma_{c}^{\infty}(E):(\psi,\varphi)_{E}=\int_{M}\langle\psi_{p},\varphi_{p}\rangle_{E_{p}}\,d\mathrm{vol}_{g}(p)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\psi=0$$
for every fixed $\psi\in \Gamma_{c}^{\infty}(E)$.Somehow, I would like to conclude that the above condition implies $\langle\psi_{p},\varphi_{p}\rangle_{E_{p}}=0$ at any point $p$, since then, non-degeneracy of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{E_{p}}$ proves the claim. However, this is not true in general, since the fact that the integral over $\langle\psi,\varphi\rangle_{E}\in C^{\infty}(M)$ is zero does not imply the integrand to be zero.

The claim is indeed true. The proof requires a bit more work, but is still faily easy. Now, instead of proving non-degenaracy using the definition you gave, it is in fact a bit easier to prove the equivalent claim
$$\forall\psi\in\Gamma_{c}^{\infty}(E)\backslash\{0\}\quad\exists \varphi\in\Gamma_{c}^{\infty}(E):\quad (\psi,\varphi)_{E}\neq 0$$
So, lets take $\psi\in\Gamma_{c}^{\infty}(E)$ with $\psi\neq 0$. In order to construct a $\varphi\in\Gamma_{c}^{\infty}(E)$ with $(\psi,\varphi)_{E}\neq 0$, the idea is to localise the problem. A sketch of the proof is as follows:

By assumption, there is a point $p_{0}\in M$ such that $\psi_{p_{0}}\neq 0$. Now, lets choose a small open neighbourhood $U$ of $p_{0}$ such that $\psi_{p_{0}}\neq 0$ and such that the bundle $E$ can be trivialiased on $U$, which allows us to locally view sections of $E$ as vector-valued functions. This can of course always be obtained by choosing $U$ small enough.
Now, by non-degeneracy of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{E_{p_{0}}}$, we find a vector $\varphi_{p_{0}}\in E_{p_{0}}$ such that $\langle\psi_{p_{0}},\varphi_{p_{0}}\rangle_{E_{p_{0}}}\neq 0$ (lets say $>$ without loss of generality, since otherwise we will replace $\varphi$ in the construction below by $-\varphi$). Now, lets extend this vector $\varphi_{p_{0}}$ locally to some smooth local section $\varphi\in\Gamma(E\vert_{U})$, potentially by shrinking the neighbourhood $U$ a bit.$^{1}$
Next, we choose a bump function $\chi\in C^{\infty}_{c}(M)$ with $\chi(p_{0})=1$ and $\mathrm{supp}(\chi)\subset V$ for a sufficiently small neighbourhood $V\subset U$ of $p_{0}$ and set $\varphi^{\prime}:=\chi\varphi$. Now, choosing the neighbourhood $V$ small enough, we will obtain eventually
$$(\psi,\varphi^{\prime})_{E}=\int_{M}\langle\psi,\varphi^{\prime}\rangle_{E}\,vol_{g}=\int_{V}\langle\psi,\varphi^{\prime}\rangle_{E}\,vol_{g}>0$$
since the integral is dominated by the contribution at $p_{0}$. Hence, $\varphi^{\prime}$ is the required section.


$^{1}$ This can for example be obtained by choosing some local frame $\{e^{i}\}_{i}\in\Gamma(E\vert_{U})$ of $E$. Then, we define $\varphi$ by setting $$\varphi_{p}=\sum_{i}\varphi^{i}e_{i}(p)$$ for all $p\in U$, where $\varphi^{i}$ are the (constant) coefficients defined by $\varphi_{p_{0}}=\sum_{i}\varphi^{i}e_{i}(p_{0})$.
